# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: str

Tags: python, string, integer

Probably my coding isn't so good and some lines wouldn't make much sense or are not necessary, but the code purpose is dead-simple:

I want to create a function that uses an input(string), and convert it as an integer, which is going to be use in a math problem.
Plus: I want my code to interpret a random generated number and print it as its string equivalent:

```
### 'one' --> 1
### 'zero' --> 0 

import random

##'one' == 1
##'zero' == 0

def name_to_number(name):
    if name == 'one':
        return 1

def number_to_name(comp_number):
    if comp_number == 1:
        return 'one'

def lit_for_num(name):
    '''(str) -> str'''

    comp_number = random.randrange(0,1)
    equation = (abs(comp_number - int(name)))
    if equation == 0:
        print('Hallo!')
        return 'Computer draws' + comp_number
    else:
        return 'Computer draws 0'
```

Any help is very much thanked.

Comment: `name` isn't defined in `lit_for_num`, but you use it in `int(name)`. Did you mean `int(guess)` instead?

Comment: Yeah you are right... I just fixed it

Comment: @GaryJ.EspitiaS. Seems to me you wanted to call `name_to_number(name)` instead of `int(name)` if your input is `one`. The reasons you are seeing the error is because your input is `one` and hence `int('one')` will give you that error.

Comment: I see, this actually fixes it... but now I have the query... that it seems that it always throws the `else` condition...

Comment: @GaryJ.EspitiaS. I posted the explanation in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you seem to be using `one` as input, and hence
`int('one')` will give you that error.

Secondly, in:

```
comp_number = random.randrange(0,1)
...
if equation == 0:
    print('Hallo!')
    return 'Computer draws' + comp_number
else:
    return 'Computer draws 0'
```

the `else` clause will always be called because `comp_number` is always 0.

[`rand.randrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange) is similar to `choice(range(start, stop, step))`, which means `randrange(0,1)` will always return 0. You would want `randrange(0,2)` instead if you want to either `0` or `1`. Or, use [`random.randint(0,1)`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint) instead, which will include end points `0` and `1`.

As a bonus, to process text number to number, you may want to consider [text2num](https://github.com/ghewgill/text2num/blob/master/text2num.py) written by [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I feel a bit silly for not knowing this kind of functions' details.

Comment: @GaryJ.EspitiaS. You are welcome! It sure has bitten me when I was learning too -- that's how I know :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below works just fine with me. All I had to do was change `return 'Computer draws'+comp_number` with `return 'Computer draws'+str(comp_number)` as well as `random.randrange(0,1)` to `random.randrange(0,2)`.

```
### 'one' --> 1
### 'zero' --> 0 

import random

##'one' == 1
##'zero' == 0

def name_to_number(name):
    if name == 'one':
        return 1

def number_to_name(comp_number):
    if comp_number == 1:
        return 'one'

def lit_for_num(name):
    '''(str) -> str'''

    comp_number = random.randrange(0,1)
    equation = (abs(comp_number - int(name)))
    if equation == 0:
        print('Hallo!')
        return 'Computer draws' + str(comp_number)
    else:
        return 'Computer draws 0'
```